# How to close settings in Path of Diablo

Tags: diablo-ii

I installed the Path of Diablo mod on Diablo 2 + LoD and it works, except for one problem.

Whenever I start the game the Path of Diablo settings are in the top left of the play area, taking about 1/4 of the screen size. 
There are useful options on that screen but I cannot close it.

There is no "close" icon and I tried every key on keyboard but it is still there.
Being so big it prevents clicking on the are below, actually making the game much harder.

Do you know how to close that window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the settings window to close it. You have to right click on the top part of the window, even on the "SETTINGS" part itself would work.

You can also drag the window around, it doesn't have to always be in the upper left area.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click the word Settings at the top of the window like so: [image]